# How to Change CharField Choice List Behaviour

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-1.9

As you can see below, I have **model with CharField**.  The user can choose one of the value inside **ROLE_CHOICE**.

**Question**: How can I make some values unavailable but you can still see them in the selection.

Currently, I have tried the following code but it makes some values invisible, which is not what I want (I want them disabled, not invisible).

**model.py**:

```
ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ('developer', 'Developer'),
        ('business_analyst', 'Business analyst'),
        ('system_analysts', 'System analysts'),
)


class Membership (models.Model):
    ***OTHER FIELDS***
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES,)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MembershipForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['role'].choices = tuple(choice for choice in ROLE_CHOICES if choice[0] not in ['developer'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
changed the disabled to position 0 in inner list!
forms.py

```
class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MembershipForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['role'].choices = tuple(choice if choice[0] not in ['developer'] else ({"label":choice[1],"disabled":True},choice[0]) for choice in ROLE_CHOICES )
```

Here,

```
tuple(choice if choice[0] not in ['developer'] else ({"label":choice[1],"disabled":True},choice[0]) for choice in ROLE_CHOICES )
```

will give

```
(('manager', 'Manager'), ( {'disabled': True, 'label': 'developer'}, Developer), ('business_analyst', 'Business analyst'), ('system_analysts', 'System analysts'))
```

That is, for all fields that needs to be disabled, you need to add the label and disabled attribute!

and that should do the trick!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, I tried your code but unfortunately it didnt work. It still selectable. I added picture to my post. You can see how it looks like, сheck it pls. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have added the edits! Let me know if you still have the error!

Comment: I tested it. It still selectable user can select developer but form validation works. In fact it is not what you need. How do you think maybe I need disabled selection in template and not in form. Look post again pls. I edit the picture.

Comment: Thank you for this link but I have this error when try to use this custom widget: ` from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode ImportError: cannot import name 'force_unicode'` I am really comfused now.

Comment: In official documentaion I found that new name of `force_unicode` is `force_text`. I changed it to force_text but developer is still selectable. So sad =(

Comment: I added `widgets = {"role": SelectWithDisabled()}` to Meta class of my MembershipForm. Is it correct? How do you think where I did mistake?

Comment: should it be `widget=SelectWithDisabled` ?

Comment: I notice that option html looks like this `<option value="{'disabled': True, 'label': 'Developer'}">developer</option>` But it disabled must be after value attribute. How to fix it?